# Ошибка в Visual Studio? - Shared Project и Директивы препроцессора - Подсветка синтаксиса

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь использовать тип проекта Shared Project. Создал тестовый sulution, в котором два консольных приложения "ConsoleApp1" и "ConsoleApp2". А также проект "SharedProject1" типа Shared Project. Консольные приложения имеют ссылки на Shared Project. В первом консольном приложение определена директива препроцессора "NET35", а во втором "NET40". В Shared Project имеется один простой класс Person, который использует директивы определённые в консольных приложения:

```
class Person
    {

#if NET35
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Дмитрий";
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "Ростов";
#endif
#if NET40
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Алексей";
        public string LastName { get; set; } = "Морозин";
#endif
    }
```

Проблема в том, что подсветка синтаксиса некорректно работает, когда компилирую проект ConsoleApp2, для которого определена директива NET40. Соответствующий код для NET40 выполняется, но цвет его серый, что видно на картинке ниже (специально код привожу в виде картинке, чтобы сохранились цвета и курсор исполнения кода):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогичное поведение для Visual Studio Community 2015 и 2017. Как определяется, какая директива препроцессора будет использоваться для SharedProject1? Может я использую не тот инструмент для такой задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Решение - требуется выбрать проект в верхнем левом угле.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]